# Type cannot be used as an index type

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

Go to https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html and paste:

```
let userTypes = {};
let keys = Object.keys[userTypes];
```

receive error:

```
error TS2538: Type '{}' cannot be used as an index type.
```

Why?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`Object.keys` returns an array of properties. You can't index an array using an object; you must use a number to represent the offset from the start of the array.

As a equivalent example, what do you expect this code to do?:

```
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
console.log(a[{}]);
```

It's nonsensical.

Edit:
After reading the OP's comments and looking over then code again, I realized that my assessment was wrong. While *a* problem is that the original code is attempting to index the `keys` function using an object literal, the real issue is the use of square brackets instead of parentheses. This will work:

```
let keys = Object.keys(userTypes);
```

It calls `keys` with `userTypes` instead of index with it.

Comment: I expect it to return undefined... :D

Comment: Should have been `Object.keys(userTypes)`

Comment: In reality, I actually misunderstood the code. I was thinking your problem was simply the fact you were indexing with a `{}`, which it kind of is since you're trying to index the `keys` function using the object literal. You're right though that the real problem is the incorrect use of square brackets. I'll update my answer.

Comment: I would expect it equivalent to `{ '[object Object]': undefined }[ {} ]`.

Answer (score -1):

The simplest solution is to add empty string with item.key [as a index].

```js
let userTypes = {};
let keys = Object.keys[userTypes+''];
```

We can also use this trick in *ngFor where we use keyValue pipe for objects!!